# How to call a click on the Google Maps Marker marker in UI Automator?

Tags: google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-uiautomator

In UIAutomator Viewer can see that the markers do not have anything unique except the index.
[image: UI Automator]

I tried to simulate a click on a specific marker in the following way:

```
UiObject gMap = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().descriptionContains("Google Map"));
UiObject marker = mDevice.findObject(gMap.getSelector().index(1));
marker.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

But the click did not happen. How can I simulate clicking on the markers?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `gMap.getSelector()`. You should use `childSelector` to search markers inside map view

```
UiObject marker = mDevice.findObject(UiSelector()
        .descriptionContains("Google Map")
        .childSelector(UiSelector().instance(1))
)
```

And try to use `marker.waitForExists(5000)` before clicking. Usually they appear not immediately on map

Answer (score 0):

Using [CulebraTester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) and a sample map application (as shown)

[image]

which has 3 markers: the 2 red have title and snippet and the blue doesn't, you can see how the generated code differ.

```
mDevice.findObject(By.desc("title_of_marker1. snippet_of_marker1.").clazz("android.view.View").text(Pattern.compile("")).pkg("com.example.diego.mymapapplication")).clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
mDevice.findObject(By.desc("title_of_marker2. snippet_of_marker2.").clazz("android.view.View").text(Pattern.compile("")).pkg("com.example.diego.mymapapplication")).clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
mDevice.findObject(By.desc("Google Map").clazz("android.view.View").text(Pattern.compile("")).pkg("com.example.diego.mymapapplication")).clickAndWait(Until.newWindow(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
```

the 3rd selector is too broad and ambiguous.

I guess if you add title and/or snippet you'll have no problem clicking on them.